# Command to run lightread

Tags: rss, lightread

I've installed **lightread** which works fine. I can open lightread from dash but there is no `lightread` command in **terminal**. May be the command to lightread is something other than `lightread`. So, what is the command to run **lightread**?

Answer (score 0):

actually the command to run it is

> lightread

However probably you have the launcher missing. Try running the menu editing tool. Type

> alacarte

Then go to the section "internet" (or the one you want to create the shortcut in), click on "new element" button (top right of the program window) and fill the boxes:

> In program: Lightread
>
> In command: lightread
>   (attention to the minuscules)
>
> Description: Is a great google reader client

Now try to search it from the dash, for sure it will be there! :)

Cheers! :)

Comment: I have **lightread** launcher in dash but the problem was I don't have `lightread` command in _terminal_.

Comment: oh, so you have to add it in /usr/bin as a symbolic link! :)
sudo ln -s /where_is_lightread/lightread /usr/bin/lightread

to find where is the executable, you may run:
sudo updatedb
locate lightread